# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning に対応する(消す)には

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, framework, parse.com

XCode6 において以下のような警告がでます。

```
Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/myname/Documents/XCode/project/parse-library-1.6.1/ParseUI.framework/ParseUI', framework linker option at /Users/myname/Documents/XCode/project/parse-library-1.6.1/ParseUI.framework/ParseUI is not a dylib
```

この警告に対応したい (出ないようにしたい) のですが、どうすればよいでしょうか?

Parse を使って開発していたのですが、
ある時を境に突然ヘッダーの `#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>` が読み込めなくなり、
`file not found` というエラーが出るようになりました。
これを解決する為に、
新しい ParseSDK をダウンロードして差し替えたのですが、
今度はこの警告が出るようになってしまい解決策が思いつきません。

Framework のパスを修正したり、
TARGETS の test の方にも Framework のパスを指定してみましたが、
この警告が消えません。
どなたか、似たような経験がございましたら解決策をご教示ください。

Comment: Xcode6.0以降、フレームワークの組み込み方法は、新しい方法が追加されました。フレームワーク自体のパッケージファイルを直接、自分のprojectに追加する方法です。AdMobなども、最新版では、この方式になり、install方法が変わっています。ParseSDKのことは、しりませんが、新しいバージョンで、組み込み方が変わったのに古い方法をつづけていたり、古い設定が残っていたりしませんか？